# unreadable format of SOAP response

Tags: java, wcf, soap

I am using SOAP in java.
While reading from the socket, I am getting response in un-readable font/encoding.
Since I am a new user, I cant upload the image.

I am unable to understand the font/encoding of the contents or even the cause of such font/encoding.
Any ideas upon how to convert it into readable format using java?

Thanks

Comment: You should now be able to upload the image

Comment: @hugh no it says i need 10 points to be able to upload pic while I have 6 as of now

Comment: Can you host the image elsewhere for the moment? Like http://photobucket.com